# Building DOSBox with X11 support on OS X

Tags: macos, compilation, x11, dosbox, xquartz

I've been trying to communicate with my DOSBox window using [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) on OS X, but all my efforts have led to nothing. However, [this project](http://richard.to/programming/wolfenstein-3d-ai-part-3.html) shows that it is possible to use `xdotool` on DOSBox with X11 under Lubuntu, so I guess the problem lies in the fact that DOSBox for OS X does not support X11. What I've tried so far is launching DOSBox (installed from brew) in a XQuartz terminal, and trying to get the window ID with `xdotool`, which only works for X11 application windows (like xterm and xclock) so far. I've also tried to run the code from the project I linked, which uses C++ and the X11 C library, but that also wasn't able to find the window.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for building applications (and DOSBox in special) on OS X with X11 support? So far TK and Qt (I believe they are build systems that are able to build cross platform) seem the best next directions I can find, but I'm not sure if I can use them for my purpose.

What I'm trying to accomplish in general is to send keyboard signals and get pixel values from DOSBox (the exact same thing as the project I linked), so I'm also open to suggestions for doing it in an alternative way. 
I'm not interested in cliclick tool (a similar tool similar to xdotool that is native to OS X), as I believe I can't use it to send signals non-active windows and because Linux support is important for this project.

I've installed DOSBox (and DOSBox-x) from homebrew and from source,  and tried XQuartz versions 2.7.8 - 2.7.10.

Comment: There is no general method, each application may support it in its own way, or not at all. In particular, dosbox uses SDL for graphics, and if you have SDL built without X11 support, dosbox won't be able to use X11.

Comment: I have SDL installed with X11 support, would it then be as simple as building DOSBox while linking to that SDL?

Comment: Probably, why not give it a try?

Comment: I tried both building DOSBox with the homebrew SDL that was in turn build with the "--with-x11" option, and with a SDL environment that I build myself with all x11 options enabled in the configure and cocoa and carbon video disabled. I hoped that the last build would sort of force DOSBox to be compiled only for X11, but unfortunately it still starts with the Aqua/OS X windowing server. Any tips?

Comment: My osx-fu ends here :(